# Jump from/to loginscreen and send to specific controller (iPhone sdk)

Tags: iphone, objective-c, authentication, uiviewcontroller, ios5

I've been struggling with this for a while now.

And I've found some useful stuff, but I still feel like I've got the need to post here to hear peoples opinion.

Sometime I want to be able to send users to certain screens. If the app is reloaded I want to send them back to the screen where they left off and if they cannot be authorized anytime during login (if their password is changed elsewhere) I want to be able to kick them to the loginscreen.

To achieve this, I would add segues to all controllers from a "root" controller and then add segues from all controllers to the login controller. Then I could send them wherever with  `performSegueWithIdentifier`.

BUT, is this really the way to go? Seems a bit inflexible and ugly. Is there a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend implementing your login screen inside a UIWindow. This way you pop this window above any other view in your normal window regardless of where it is in the view hierarchy or modal.

Comment: Although I didnt do exactly this, this really led me to what I think is the solution for me! Thanks! I ended up with having my AppDelegate perform an animation from one UIViewController to another, and I can use that to send to someone to a "login screen"!